# Need to show SQL partial empty results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to show empty rows for BRANDS too. I mean, there is a third brand not shown in this query, look:

```
SELECT 
  da_brands.name AS brand_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT da_deals.id) AS total_deals,
  0 AS total_downloaded_coupons,
  0 AS total_validated_coupons,
  COUNT(da_logs.id) AS total_likes 
FROM
  da_brands,
  da_deals 
  LEFT JOIN da_logs 
    ON da_logs.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id 
    AND da_logs.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id 
    AND da_logs.type = 'deal_like' 
WHERE da_brands.fk_club_id = 6 
  AND da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id 
  AND da_brands.date <= NOW() 
GROUP BY da_brands.name 
ORDER BY da_brands.name ASC
```

RESULTS:

```
brand_name  total_deals total_downloaded_coupons    total_validated_coupons total_likes
Marca2  2   0   0   1
Marca1  9   0   0   4
```

This conditional is showing only brands within deals but i want all brands...:

```
        AND da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id
```

Any idea what statement should i use?

Thank you so much.!!!

Comment: move this `AND da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id` condition before where clause

Comment: I got this error:
Unknown column 'da_brands.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: it doesn't go directly above the WHERE clause like @M Khalid said.  You need to explicitly left join to the da_deals table (you're doing an implicit inner join now), and put that one line in the predicate (the ON statement) for the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following line in the WHERE predicate is the problem...

```
AND da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id
```

You need to `LEFT JOIN` to da_deals, the same way you did to da_logs, and move that line above into the ON statement for the join.

See below...

```
SELECT 
  da_brands.name AS brand_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT da_deals.id) AS total_deals,
  0 AS total_downloaded_coupons,
  0 AS total_validated_coupons,
  COUNT(da_logs.id) AS total_likes 
FROM da_brands
LEFT JOIN da_deals 
ON da_brands.id = da_deals.fk_brand_id
LEFT JOIN da_logs 
ON da_logs.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id 
AND da_logs.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id 
AND da_logs.type = 'deal_like' 
WHERE da_brands.fk_club_id = 6 
AND da_brands.date <= NOW() 
GROUP BY da_brands.name 
ORDER BY da_brands.name ASC
```